# Custom python Intellisense for VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plugins, intellisense

How to create our custom python intellisense for VScode?
Existence intellisense is not supported to my python library.

Comment: I think it's not on VSCode. More on how you installed or managing your library. Maybe try installing your library in the environment VSCode is using?

Comment: I have installed my library through PIP only, then after anyone want to consume my library existence Intelisense is not supported. I am using VScode editor.

Comment: Can we create our own python extension or plugin or Intellisense?

Comment: Well, you can always create a plugin or intellisense but for your case it's not necessary. Can you create a virtual environment and install your library there. Then change the VSCode python path to the virtual environment and see if your library is detected? There is no reason for the vscode python plugin to not detect your library unless there is something wrong with the setup.

Comment: It is detecting my library from VScode, but I want to make some custom python plugin for my package(Like: user want to know all the parameters from other json or .txt file)

Ex:  test.comment.write("") 
When user press double quotes, we should populate all the parameters, then user can select parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the [python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension to get IntelliSense. For customization, I think you can refer to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) of vscode.

Comment: I tried with those python plugin, but I want to create some custom Intellisense for my package (Like: user want to know all the parameters from other json or .txt file)

Comment: I want to make some custom python plugin for my package(Like: user want to know all the parameters)

Ex:  test.comment.write("") 
When user press double quotes, we should populate all the parameters, then user can select parameter.

Comment: Obviously, this is not the service provided by the built-in IntelliSense of Python extension. What you described is more like developing extensions and relying on a python package. I'm sorry I can't provide more help.

Comment: Thank you, if you have any suggestions or guidlines, please share